# "During" a Period of Time

Tags: grammar, word-usage, time

I'm working on a sentence (example below). It doesn't quite feel right:

> I tried to count the number of cars driven during 1980-1990.

Specifically, the issue here is about *usage* of the preposition 'during' with the time period '1980-1990'. I'm not so sure how to treat that period as a grammatical object.

I've considered some alternatives:

> I tried to count the number of cars driven throughout 1980-1990.

(Doesn't sound good.)

> I tried to count the number of cars driven between 1980 and 1990.

(Ambiguous due to not specifying that the range of years is inclusive.)

Any suggestions on how I should do this?

Comment: It's really inclusive of both 1980 and 1990? You're really studying an ***eleven*** year period?

Comment: *driven by whom*? By any motorist or by yourself? "I tried to count the number of cars I had driven..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All I think you're missing here is being specific:

> I tried to count the number of cars driven during the period
>   1980-1990.

Answer (score 1):

"I tried counting the number of cars driven from 1980 to 1990."

"From" defines a beginning and end. "tried counting" rolls off the tongue better than "tried to count" IMO; fewer words, nicer rhythm.

Comment: imho there is a difference in meaning between "tried to count" and "tried counting".

Answer (score 1):

You have to be specific about dates. If you want to include the whole years of 1980 and 1990, you just say

> "I tried to count the number of cars driven from Jan 1st, 1980 through Dec 31st, 1990." [(through = up to and including)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/through)

If you say

> "I tried to count the number of cars driven during the eighties."

that wouldn't include 1990.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's hard to get rid of the ambiguity unless you deal with it directly.

> I tried to count the number of cars driven in the period from the beginning of 1980 to the end of 1990.
>
> I tried to count the number of cars driven in the years 1980-1990 (inclusive).